# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function after adding a submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a submenu to my website which uses a small piece of jquery to control the css classes. The menu works fine, but on one of my pages I have a slider. The slider used to work, but now it gives me an uncaught type error at the `$('#banner-slide').bjqs({`

So on the other pages, without the slider the menu works. On the other hand the slider without the menu works, but together I get the error.

Code as complete as possible (otherwise it would be too long)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="slider/js/bjqs-1.3.js"></script>


<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array( 
                    'items'=>array( 
                        array('label'=>'OVER', 
                          'items'=>array( 
                            array('label'=>'Geschiedenis', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'sub1')), 
                            array('label'=>'Bestuur', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'sub1')), 
                            array('label'=>'Carriere', 
                              'items'=>array( 
                                array('label'=>'Werken', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub1')), 
                                array('label'=>'Stage', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                              ), 
                            ), 
                            array('label'=>'Diensten', 
                              'items'=>array( 
                                array('label'=>'Advies & Ondersteuning', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub1')), 
                                array('label'=>'Bemiddeling', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Organisatieadvies', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Aanvragen subsidies', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Ontwikkeling', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                              ), 
                            ), 
                            array('label'=>'Projecten', 
                              'items'=>array( 
                                array('label'=>'De trap op', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub1')), 
                                array('label'=>'Zuidelijk Wo-man connect', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Taalondersteuning', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Taalkoppers', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                                array('label'=>'Iets', 'url'=>array('/site/page','view'=>'subsub2')), 
                              ), 
                            ), 
                          ), 
                        ),
                        array('label'=>'VACATUREBANK', 'url'=>array('/vacature/index')),
                        array('label'=>'NIEUWS', 'url'=>array('/nieuws/index')), 
                        array('label'=>'AGENDA', 'url'=>array('/agenda/index')),
                        array('label'=>'CONTACT', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'contact')),
                    ), 
            )); ?> 


<div id="banner-slide">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <?php
            $slides = Plaatjes::model()->findAll();

            foreach($slides AS $r) {  
                echo '<li><a href="'.$r->url.'"><img class="plaatje" src="'.$r->pad.'"></a><div class="ondertitel"><div class="onder">'.$r->ondertitel.'</div></div></li>';
            }
        ?>    
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var breedte = $("#content").width();
        var hoogte = 540;

        if(breedte < 960)
            hoogte = 435;

        if(breedte < 768)
            hoogte = 300;

        $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
          animtype      : 'slide',
          height        : hoogte,
          width         : breedte,
          responsive    : true,
          randomstart   : true
        });

    });

$("#nav li").hover(

function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("parent")) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    }
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Make sure `#banner-slide` is on the apge and make sure you are calling that library

Comment: The banner-slide is on this page and works fine if I remove the code to control my classes. I only don't understand why they don't work together. Or am I missing something else you're saying?

Comment: Can you post the complete code after you have added the class changing code? Instead of 2 blocks, update the code to have the complete code

Comment: Did it. But it looks like a javascript problem and the blocks were the only javascript involved. Hope you can still help me out here..

Comment: Have you tried moving the nav hover to inside of document ready? It should be in there

Comment: Yes, didn't work eather. Think the jQuery interacted in some kind of way. Made a css dropdown manually and now everything works... Thanks for the help!